# How to get current date in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I'm using visual studio 2010 do developt my Windows phone application!
I'm newbie and i don't know how to show current date in follow format

For ex

I use

> String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",date);

Out put:

> 09/04/2012 (this date is my datetime format)

But, I want out put exactly is (date only without "0"):

> 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well one option is just:

```
string text = date.Day.ToString();
```

Or if you still want to use date/time formatting you could use:

```
string text = string.Format("{0:%d}", date);
```

Note that here the `%` is required to specify that you want the `d` to be a single character [*custom* format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) rather than just a [standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) (where `d` means "short date string").

If you want the rest of your date format, but *only* want to change how the day of month is represented, you can just change the `dd` to `d`:

```
string text = string.Format("{0:d/MM/yyyy}", date);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! THis is exactly what i want ! nice day to you ! thanks

Comment: I just want to show date of today (not include month, year, etc)

Comment: @user1023135: Okay, then I'd definitely use the first version :)

Comment: @JonSkeet strange that `DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M")` is ok but DateTime.Now.ToString("d")  aint....

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Not really - because single-letter format specifiers usually indicate *standard* formats such as "short date". Read the links in the post for more details.